# correct name of mathematical property

Tags: functions, terminology, inverse

I am developing a program that transforms artifacts in one (computer) language to artifacts in another language. In my program there are certain border line situations where the result of applyin the default transformation of an artifact A in language X produces B in language Y. But after transforming B back to language X, the result is not the same as A.

So I have (in certain border cases):

$x \neq f^{-1}  (f(x))$

I am looking for the best way to describe this in the documentation of my program.
My question is: What is the name of the mathematical property of certain function that implies ?:

$x = f^{-1}  (f(x))$

I need this to clearly explain that this property does not always hold in my program.

Comment: Do you mind my asking how severe the failure of this property is? For example, is there some sense in which $f^{-1}(f(x))$ is equivalent to *x*, without being literally identical?

Comment: well, that depends on the language I start. The language A has more primitive data types than language B. So if $x$ is in artifact in A, then my transformation function does not have a left inverse (there are more that one type in A that is mapped to the same type in B). However, if I start with an artifact in B (transforming it to A and then back to B), the function has a left inverse. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: I think I understand: the map from B to A is one-one, but the map from A to B is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ you could say: $f$ has a left inverse, or $f$ is injective, or that $f$ is a monomorphism ($f$ is monic).

In the program you could say that that $f$ does not have a left inverse or that $f^{-1}$ is not $f$'s left inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the notation $f^{-1}$ is reserved for "the function such that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ and $f(f^{-1}(y)) = y$ for all (*x,y*) in the (domain,codomain) of *f*". Sometimes the notation is still used when only one of these two properties holds, but if neither of them holds you really shouldn't call the function $f^{-1}$ in the first place.

As for terminology, if *f* and *g* are functions and $g(f(x)) = x$ for all *x* in the domain of *f*, then:

- *g* is a  a **left inverse** or **retraction** of *f*;
- *f* is a **right inverse** or **section** of *g*.

Comment: I see, but the point is that I need to leave clear in the documentation of my program that my function f does not have that property, given that there are few counter-examples. Do you think that it is fine if I say something like: "Being f our default conversion function, it is not true that for all x in the domain of f:

$f^{-1}  (f(x)) = x$

 Where x is a language artefact."

Comment: For documentation I would probably write "$f^{-1}$ is not a left inverse of $f$," since *left inverse* is easier to guess the meaning of than *section*. Then again I might just write, "It is not guaranteed that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$," so that there's no guessing at all.